# Get DISTINCT value from related model

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 models. `Users` and `Ips`. `Users` relation :

```
return array(
    'ips' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'Ips', ['user_id' => 'id']]
);
```

Ips model has fields `id, user_id, ip`.

I need to get all `Users` with its unique `Ips`.

```
$users = $model->with(['ips' => [
    'select' => 'ip', 
    'distinct' => true
]])->findAll();
```

doesn`t work the way I need. Probably it gets unique by field `id`.

Thanks for response!

Comment: You know, saving full IPs is against personal data usage? NSA?

Comment: This project is building for internal company usage, not for public usage. Is it illegal?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your relation like so:

`return array(
    'ips' => [self::HAS_MANY, 'Ips', 'user_id']
);`

Comment: It dosn`t change nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try GROUP BY

```
$users = User::model()->with(array(
    'ips'=>array(
        'group'=>'user_id, ip',
    )
))->findAll();
```

Hope it helps